# Patching any properties of sendAs in gmail api overrides displayName to empty string if user has display name set to 'your name in Google accounts'

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to set my email signature using the [`Users.settings.sendAs: patch`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/patch) gmail api method. However, when I have the '(your name in Google accounts)' radio button selected in Gmail's name setting, patching just the `signature` field results in the second checkbox becoming selected in the gmail name setting with an empty string in the text box. I would expect that using the `patch` method shouldn't be changing anything I didn't explicitly specify.

Now I see that when I make a gmail api request for the `sendAs` object, it returns an empty string regardless of which checkbox is selected in the gmail interface, so it seems like maybe the API is just not aware of this setting and is implicitly overriding it with an empty string regardless of what data is actually in the patch request?

I'd like to be able to safely update a signature without having to worry about this unexpected side effect. Am I missing something? Is there some way to leave the `displayName` field alone when patching the `sendAs` object? Or maybe at least some way to explictly set it to be the default name in the google account? I suspect this is a bug, but I'd love to be proven wrong or find a workaround.

Comment: What API scope you are using with this?

Comment: This is a bug.  It has been reported at https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4819.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug.  It has been fixed: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4819#c5